# Does the order of operands affect performance of MUL operation?

Tags: assembly, arm

I've heard about order of operands in `MUL` affects performance.
In ARM assembly, does the order of operands affects performance of MUL operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This notion, along with the operand restriction [Michael mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33104746/3156750), is a result of the early ARM cores using [Booth's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth's_multiplication_algorithm) to implement the multiplier. The *very* early ones used the destination register directly as the working register, hence you'd end up with a nonsense result if that destroyed one of your input operands in the process - later cores with better multipliers (ARM7TDMI onwards, I think) kept the workings internal to the multiplier unit and only wrote back to the registers at the end, hence that particular restriction was eventually lifted entirely in the ARMv6 architecture. However, such iterative algorithms may also be able to terminate early, and the v6 architecture does still formalise the behaviour of earlier implementations with a note that any implementation of early termination must be based on the *second* operand.

In practice what that means is that, on a suitably ancient core, the number of cycles needed for the operation `MUL Rd, Rm, Rs` might [depend on how many non-sign bits `Rs` has](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0210c/Chdjffcc.html), but on ARMv5 and later designs you almost certainly assume a fast fixed-time multiplier where it makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: The fast multiplier is optional on Cortex-M0. The timing is nevertheless fixed at 32-cycles for the slow option.

Comment: Thank you for comment. However I can't understand well. Can you please explain which is faster for instance, between `MUL r1, #3, #17` and `MUL r1, #17, #3`(I know operands should be register but this is too cramped)?

Comment: @doynax Yeah, I deliberately glossed over that as it's still fixed-time ;)

Comment: @soonoo As a rough approximation, try considering an even simpler iterative algorithm that would result in `3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+3` vs. `17+17+17` for those. And as I say, unless you're working with an ARM7TDMI or ARM9, feel free to ignore it entirely.

Comment: um... I'm working on ARM9 but there is no difference in performance(states and code size) How can I find difference?

Comment: @soonoo Actually, most ARM9s around today are probably built around the v5 ARM9E core with a [fixed-cycle multiplier](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0240b/I1028171.html), rather than [the original v4 ARM9TDMI core](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0180a/i1000003.html) - your SoC's reference manual should hopefully reveal the details.

Answer (score 0):

Performance, no (AFAIK). However, the operand order can matter for other reasons on some ARM acrhitectures. From the ARM7TDMI instruction set manual (DDI 0029E):

> **4.7.1 Operand restrictions**
>   The destination register Rd must not be the same as the operand register Rm. R15
>   must not be used as an operand or as the destination register.

So, for example, one should not write `mul r1,r1,r2`, but `mul r1,r2,r1` would be ok. The manual doesn't seem to specify exactly what will happen if you use the same register for `Rd` and `Rm`, and it might depend on the exact implementation. The ARM ARM (DDI 0100E) says that the result is *UNPREDICTABLE*.